# Custom Validator does not work on checking empty password

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, bcrypt

I am using bcrypt to hash the password of a user. Therefore I have the following interface:

```
app.post("/user", function(req, res, next) {
    // hash the password asynchronously
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, null, null, function(err, hash) {
        var newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            password: hash,
            email: req.body.email
        });
        newUser.validate(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                logger.info("User registration aborted: " + err.toString());
                return res.status(400).json(err);
            } else {
                newUser.save(function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).json(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(user.username + " saved succesfully.");
                        logger.info("User " + user._id + " registered.");
                        return res.json(user);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The user is able to enter an empty password (""), which will be hashed as well. I don't want that the user should be able to create passwords that are short then x and longer then y characters. Therefore I want to use a custom validator to abort that:

```
UserSchema.path("password").validate(function (value) {
    bcrypt.compare("", value, function(err, equal) {
        console.log(this.username + ": " + value + ", " + equal);
        return !equal;
    });
}, "password empty");
```

This does not work, the empty password will be hashed without getting an error. And this of course does not solve the issue of having too long or too short passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You don't store the plaintext password in mongoDB, so you can't be enforcing your password length policy as part of `UserSchema` validation. You need to do it before you get to the hashing/mongoose side of things. Something like this for example:

```
app.post("/user", function(req, res, next) {
    var pw = req.body.password;
    if (!pw || pw.length > max || pw.length < min) {
        return res.status(400).send('Password is required and must be > x and < y...');
    }

    // hash the password asynchronously
    // ...
});
```

However, you do seem to be reinventing the wheel here. Username/password login has already been done many times over. Relying on an existing widely depended upon implementation is probably a better idea than trying to roll your own. For example:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local

Comment: I am using oauth2-server as a plugin and cannot use passport-local since I am building a rest api without serving pages. I also did the same as a quick fix, the problem with that is, that the error will not be send with the other validation errors. I want to send this validation error in the same message as all possible other validation errors for other attributes in the model.

Comment: Well, if your goal is to do all validation in the same place you could front load your validation nicely by defining a JSON schema for `req.body`. In my own code I use this simple middleware I wrote that uses `tv4`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-schema

You could still do whatever you like in the mongoose validator, but keep in mind what I said, you're talking about two different schemas, and therefore two different validation methods. Also, passport works fine for rest APIs